# Json value error for Non-English character in Android App

Tags: android, json, utf-8

I want show Non-English character such as Bangla or Arabic in my App from my **JSON** file but it's showing garbage text in my App but English text work pretty well, so how can I solve this problem in Android Studio? Thanks in Advance!

This is my code, but when I run my app everything work perfectly but not showing my own text & it's not English text, other native language text.

```
private void loadData() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("leader");

                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject recieveData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    //.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")

                    LeaderModel items = new LeaderModel(
                            recieveData.getString("url"),
                            recieveData.getString("name"),
                            recieveData.getString("title"),             
                            recieveData.getString("description")
                    );

                    leaderListItems.add(items);
                }

                leaderAdapter = new LeaderAdapter(leaderListItems, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(leaderAdapter);


            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(LeaderMainPage.this, "Server error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue using this code line in my **public void onResponse(){}** method and It's work pretty well.

```
      if (response != null){
            try {
                response=new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```